# How to define dependent random variables that satisfy certain conditions?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, covariance, means

I need to define to dependent random variables $X$ and $Y$ such that $\mathrm{E}(X) = 19$ and $\mathrm{E}(Y) = 160$ but $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y) = 0$.

I was thinking about it quite a while and still didn't get the point of how to approach it.

Also, is it possible to do the same with independent variables such that $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y) > 0$ ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one of the simplest examples.  First let
$$
X = 19 + \begin{cases} \phantom{-}1 \\ \phantom{-}0 \\ -1 \end{cases}
$$
each with probability $1/3$, then let $Y = 160 + X^2 - \operatorname{E}(X^2) = 160 + X^2 - \dfrac 2 3.$

The covariance between $X$ and $X^2$ is $0$, but clearly they are dependent.

Comment: Thanks, but how is E(Y)=160 ?

Comment: @matansab $$Y = 160 + X^2 - \operatorname{E}(X^2), $$and so$$\operatorname{E}(Y) = 160 + \operatorname{E}(X^2) - \operatorname{E}(X^2).$$ Might that be equal to $160\text{?}\qquad$